# How to get start and end indices of consecutive groups of data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Given

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a":  [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ],
})
print(df)
```

> ```
>     a
> 0   1
> 1   1
> 2   1
> 3   2
> 4   2
> 5   2
> 6   2
> 7   3
> 8   3
> 9   3
> 10  3
> 11  1
> 12  1
> 13  2
> 14  2
> 15  3
> 16  3
> ```

I need to calculate the following result:

```
res_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "starts": [0, 3, 7, 11, 13, 15],
    "ends": [3, 7, 11, 13, 15, 17]
})
print(res_df)
```

> ```
>    starts  ends
> 0       0     3
> 1       3     7
> 2       7    11
> 3      11    13
> 4      13    15
> 5      15    17
> ```

---

If values were not duplicated, I could do something like zeroing out all duplicates, keeping the length of the group in groupby, then a cumsum.

However, there are duplicates, and order should be preserved.

Is there a way to do this in pandas?

---

As a follow up, I would like to calculate `starts` and `ends` just for df["a"] == 3, if it would be computationally less expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
blocks = df['a'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()

# depending on your mask
out = (df[some_mask]             
         .index.to_frame()
         .groupby(blocks)[0]
         .agg(['min','max'])
      )
out['max'] += 1
```

Output:

```
   min  max
a          
1    0    3
2    3    7
3    7   11
4   11   13
5   13   15
6   15   17
```

Comment: Thanks! Please see edit, if I knew up front I only care about starts and ends of a specific group, for example `df["a"] == 3`, can this be made faster? Also, Can you add a column to specify which group the result came from? to be able to select on that.

Comment: what do the values on `"a"` mean in the output?

Comment: @Gulzar that's just the name of the `blocks`. When you group by a series, the series' name is set as the new data's index name. Pass `as_index=False` to `groupby` if you don't wnat it.

Answer (score 1):

you could slice the index and the column a with a mask where `shift` is not equal to current value, then create a dataframe. The result could also include the original value of the column a.

```
m = df['a'].ne(df['a'].shift())
res = pd.DataFrame({'a':df.loc[m,'a'], 
                    'starts':df.index[m]})
res['ends'] = res['starts'].shift(-1, fill_value=len(df))

print(res)
    a  starts  ends
0   1       0     3
3   2       3     7
7   3       7    11
11  1      11    13
13  2      13    15
15  3      15    17
```

​